# It's time to go!

Tags: word, story, cipher

You have stolen the object.

You have completed the mission.

You're ready to get out.

There's just one little snag:

Your driver was captured and you no longer have an escape route.  You sent a communique to TFC Command on your secure device, requesting further orders, and the following string was sent back to you.

> 73 + 97 + 22 + 98 + 32

Clearly Command is unsure if you've been compromised, or not, and so they sent their response, encoded.

You must figure out how you're supposed to get out, quickly, before you're caught!  Get to it!

## Hint:

1. > The orders give a method of escape.  You already know where to go.
2. > You know who you work for, and you have a pre-planned method for decoding these messages.  You remember that the name of the organization you work for plays a part in decoding it.
3. > The organization you work for seems to be a little robin hood'ish, in everything that they do.
4. > Your organization regularly uses the + symbol to delineate things, in communiques.   They consider it ironic.
5. > I'm *positive* that you can solve this, once you've figured out what the numbers mean.

Comment: Hold on... if you expect us to figure out the result from nothing more than the communication itself, doesn't that mean that it isn't an indicator of whether or not we're compromised?

Comment: The encoding is meant to protect Command, not you.  If you're compromised, it's your own job to get safe. :)

Comment: Is there an obvious meaning for *TFC* that I'm missing?

Comment: No, but the company logo looks like this: <C

Comment: Hint 3 kind of suggests to me that I was right in the meaning of the numbers but I still haven't figured out how to interpret what they yield correctly.  

I guess I'm just not synchronized with the answer yet.

Comment: No idea - I don't know what your thought is, yet. =D

Comment: The only *existing* company named TFC with a logo vaguely resembling <C is *The Filipino Channel*. But is that Robin Hoodish?

Comment: I will admit that TFC is completely made up, but it does mean something.

Comment: Given hint 3 and 4 I was thinking about some christian organization, am I on the right track?

Comment: @karmalu No, sorry.

Comment: Is it Thieves For Charity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh my goodness, how did you make it out in the cold so long? You should take the

> Helicopter

as soon as possible.

> See, TFC is robin hoodish in that it stands for *Take From C*, where C is the Roman numeral for $100$. So you subtract each number from 100, giving $27\ 3\ 78\ 2\ 68$. The chemical symbols for the elements of these numbers are CoLiPtHeEr, which can be rearranged into **HELICOPTER**

Comment: Get to the choppaaaaaahh

Comment: Zed's dead, baby

Comment: I thought of chemical symbols but didn't connect the name/logo to the operation necessary to make it work.

Comment: @Matt I seriously considered putting "Figure out the place you need to get to", or something similar, in the puzzle, somewhere...

Answer (score 4):

One of the full forms of TFC is

> Theater Finance Command

It gave me a clue that it is something about movies and stories.

> Some of the Robin hood movies and show were released in
>  - [1973](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070608/)
>  - [1997](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115289/)
>  - [1922](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0013556/)

Other remaining numbers are 98 and 32

**Possibility 1**

> **9832 Robin Ave NE, Albuquerque** or  **3298 Robinhood Rd, Tallahassee, Florida**

**Possibility 2**

> By rearranging 98 and 32, we get 82 and 93 and the movies related to them are:
>  - [1982](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0430550)
>  - [1993](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107977)
>  So clearly, the place is related to Robin Hood. So, it must be **[Sherwood Forest, Nottinghamshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherwood_Forest)**.  Or it can also be **[Archer City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archer_City,_Texas)**

Comment: I have no clue if it's right, but I love this answer.

Comment: A nice idea, manshu, but not quite what I'm looking for.  I added another tag, a bit ago, as a clue.

Answer (score 0):

$73 + 97 + 22 + 98 + 32 = 7397229832$

Splitting it up into to halves makes:

$73972\quad29832$

Add the decimals and you get longitude and latitude of:

$73.972\quad29.832$

Comment: I like the thought process, but the result is not a location in decimal degrees.

Comment: Was the caps lock really necessary?

Comment: @Deusovi Sorry, I'm on my break at work and for my work I need cap locks on :P

Answer (score 0):

> 73 + 97 + 22 + 98 + 32

Adding up the numbers as suggested by Command gives us 322. Considering that the map is an XY plane (with North being 0°), 322° would mean 38° east of North. Since the sum was made of 5 numbers, that could probably mean that you have to travel 5 klicks in that direction to reach the rendezvous point.